# Split file text by newline Scala

Tags: scala, file-io, numbers, newline

I want to read 100 numbers from a file which are stored in such a fashion: [image: text file]

Each number is on the different line. I am not sure which data structure should be used here because later I will need to sum all these numbers altogether and extract first 10 digits of the sum.
I only managed to simply read the file, but I want to split all the text by newline separators and get each number as a list or array element:

```
val source = Source.fromFile("pathtothefile")
val lines = source.getLines.mkString
```

I would be grateful for any advice on a data structure to be used here!
Update on approach:

```
val lines = Source.fromFile("path").getLines.toList
```

Comment: How about `source.getLines`. You create one huge string, while `getLines` already gives you an iterator on each line. You can then transform it with `toStream` or `toSeq` or `toSet` as it pleases your usecase. Beware though, that all of those numbers would still be interpreted as a `String`, so you would first need to convert them to an appropriate type such as e.g. `BigInt`. For the datastructure itself, it depends on how huge that file can become and if there are multiple of them etc.

Comment: @Lichtbringer I updated the question. Thanks for an advice.

Answer (score 1):

you almost have it there, just map to BigInt, then you have a list of BigInt

```
val lines = Source.fromFile("path").getLines.map(BigInt(_)).toList
```

(and then you can use .sum to sum them all up, etc)

Comment: hi @Cassie did this answer your question?